# Exchange Web Service API really slow but only if called from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, exchangewebservices

I am trying to build a WPF application that queries our Exchange 2010 SP2 using the Exchange Web Services API.

However, I'm finding that if I use the Exchange API from a WPF application, the calls to the API are really, really slow. In fact they are two orders of magnitude slower than running the exact same code from a command-line application (some calls to the API takes 15 seconds when done from a WPF app and only 0.15 seconds when done from a command-line app).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.2.

This is the code for WPF. In particular, what runs extremely slow is the call to `folder.FindFolders` in `GetPathFolder`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace esw_testwpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemail@company.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            Folder baseFolder = FindFolderIdByPath(service, @"\Path\To\A\Known\PublicFolder", WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
        }

        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Folder FindFolderIdByPath(ExchangeService service, string path, WellKnownFolderName root)
        {
            // Specify the root folder to be searched.
            Folder rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, root);

            return GetPathFolder(rootFolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)), path, "");
        }

        public static Folder GetPathFolder(FindFoldersResults results, string lookupPath, string currentPath)
        {
            foreach (Folder folder in results)
            {
                string path = currentPath + @"\" + folder.DisplayName;
                if (lookupPath.Equals(path))
                {
                    return folder;
                }

                if (lookupPath.StartsWith(path))
                {
                    return GetPathFolder(folder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)), lookupPath, path);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this exactly the same code for command-line, which consistently runs very fast.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ewstestcmd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemail@company.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            Folder baseFolder = FindFolderIdByPath(service, @"\Path\To\A\Known\PublicFolder", WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
        }

        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Folder FindFolderIdByPath(ExchangeService service, string path, WellKnownFolderName root)
        {
            // Specify the root folder to be searched.
            Folder rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, root);

            return GetPathFolder(rootFolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)), path, "");
        }

        public static Folder GetPathFolder(FindFoldersResults results, string lookupPath, string currentPath)
        {
            foreach (Folder folder in results)
            {
                string path = currentPath + @"\" + folder.DisplayName;
                if (lookupPath.Equals(path))
                {
                    return folder;
                }

                if (lookupPath.StartsWith(path))
                {
                    return GetPathFolder(folder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)), lookupPath, path);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get such a different behavior in Exchange API response time if the code is essentially the same?

I first thought it was some kind of server-side throttling, but it does not make sense to me that the WPF variant is always very slow and the command-line variant is always very fast.

Comment: Have you tried release builds of both and running it without a debugger attached? Is it still slower?

Comment: Yes, the release build takes about the same time.  The WPF version from start to end takes 26-27 seconds while the command line version takes about one second.

Comment: However, it seems that if I change `service.TraceEnabled = true;` to `service.TraceEnabled = false;` all the extra delay disappears.  For some reason EWS tracing impacts heavily WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I changed:

```
service.TraceEnabled = true;
```

to

```
service.TraceEnabled = false;
```

all extra delay in WPF disappeared.  So it seems that, for some reason, enabling tracing for EWS in a WPF takes a huge performance hit.